# Spherical coordinates vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I understand that in cartesian coordinates  each unit vector has direction that it points in.However what would  be the analogue for spherical coordinates?while ${\displaystyle \mathbf {\hat {r}}}$ points in the direction of radial distance.What directions do the ${\displaystyle \mathbf {\hat {\theta}}}$ and ${\displaystyle \mathbf {\hat {\phi}}}$ vectors point in?Can we treat them as position vectors and how do we determine all three are perpendicular to each other?Can we cross or dot them with cartesian vectors?Thanks in advance!

Comment: HI! the direction of the unit vectors depends on how you define the angle coordinate (latitude, colatitude, azimut.. there is no unique way of interpreting spherical coordinates). Anyway, $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\phi}$ are tangent to spheres centered at the origin. Yes you can take the dot product with the standard cartesian unit vectors: it is easy if you write the spherical unit vectors in the cartesian basis, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Curvilinear_coordinates

Comment: if we were asked to  find the magnitude of a spherical vector wouldn't the $\theta$ and $\phi$ component contribute to the magnitude hence it wouldn't be its actual magnitude which is just the r component.

Comment: am    I  right?.....

Comment: It depends on what you are talking about. If you are asked to find the magnitude of the position of a point in space (namely its distance from the coordinate center), then yes, you are right: $\mathbf{x} = x \hat{\mathbf{x}} +y \hat{\mathbf{y}}+z \hat{\mathbf{z}} = r \hat{\mathbf{r}}(x,y,z)$ and $|\mathbf{x}|=r$.

Comment: thank you! that helped a lot